# How to change HTML of models (classes) in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-templates

Suppose I have a `TrueFalseQuestion` model (which only has a `question_text`) in `myproject/myapp/models.py`, and I want it to be rendered as, let's say

```
<a>Question Text</a>
<input type="radio">True</input>
<input type="radio">False</input>
```

(HTML could be wrong, not important) , in this template, only `Question Text` part changes, the input forms are always constant. So how can I implement this behaviour in Django?

An example would be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views.py file of the app, add the following.

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from models import TrueFalseQuestion

class QuestionsList(ListView):
    queryset = TrueFalseQuestion.objects.all()
    template_name = 'name_of_your_template'
```

Then inside your template, iterate over the object_list like this:

```
{%for ques in object_list%}
<a>{{ques.question_text}}</a>
<input type="radio">True</input>
<input type="radio">False</input>
{%endfor%}
```

Also, make sure to point your url to the view.

Comment: Thanks! And what if I have a view that contains multiple contentypes, like TrueFalseQuestion and MultipleChoiceQuestion?

Comment: You'll need to overwrite the get_context_data method like this:

`def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(QuestionsList,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['multiple_object_list'] = MultipleChoiceQuestion.objects.all()
    return context`

Then you can iterate over `multiple_objects_list` just as above to get the data inside this queryset.

Sorry,the indentation is screwed up in comments.

Comment: I'm actually trying to edit an existing project, and now I see that the template html file has only this : `<span class="current">
        block {{ blockPairs.number }} of {{ blockPairs.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>` , where block is a container class for questions. So how/where can I change this block's behaviour?

Comment: This is the paginator object.What exactly do you want to edit in this? If you want to use ListView's original pagination, replace your code with

`<span class="current"> block {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}. </span> `

Comment: I see. so this has nothing to do with the question / answer content. I somehow found the relevant template page somewhere else. I think I need to practice on Django's template language. Thanks again !